# What is the result of these scalar products?

Tags: geometry

We know that :

- ABCD is a square.
- BGFE is a square.
- AEB and BCG are equilateral triangles.
- AB = 1.

Here is the figure : 
[image]
I have already calculated the scalar products of BC.BE, DA.BE, EA.BE and BC.BG.
But I am stuck to find DA.EF and AE.EF (EDIT : In fact I already knew AE.EF, **in fact I am searching for DE.BF)**, what calculations should be done to find them ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose $A$ is the origin. I will assume that the order of the letters in your description puts the second letter at the "tip" of the vector.

Viewing $DA$ as a vector, it has components $(0,-1)$. Viewing $EF$ as a vector, it has components $(\sqrt{3}/2,1/2)$. You can see this in the following picture using similarity:

[image]

Can you find the scalar product of these two?

From this picture you can also see that the coordinates of $AE$ should be $(1/2,\sqrt{3}/2)$, and likewise be able to carry out the scalar product.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I am sorry, I did an error, I was searching for DE.BF and not AE.EF)

Answer (score 0):

Note we can write $\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{DA}=-\mathbf{j}$, $\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{EF}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\mathbf{i}+\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{j}$ and $\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{AE}=\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{i}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\mathbf{j}$.